# JavaFX draw shapes with delay

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, delay

How can I draw shapes with delay? 
For example at the beginning, draw few rectangles, after 1 second draw fillOval, after 3 seconds draw another oval and so on.

Comment: I would look into the sleep command, what it does it suspends the main thread (so the thread that runs the whole program) for however many seconds you tell to it. So you can have it draw something, wait some seconds, draw another thing. Otherwise it will require threading.

Comment: @SomeStudent You cannot call `sleep()` on the FX Application Thread. It will prevent the UI from being rendered.

Comment: I see, my b, wasn't sure of that, haven't done fx in forever. AH, right, now I remember, you can use FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), night); the code is from my old fx app. night here is an object for my scene and it alternates between black and white (so day and night).

Comment: You need some kind of Animation: not sure I see how you would do this with a `FadeTransition` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing an animation. For that, you should use the [Animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html).

E.g., using a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ShapeAnimationExample extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        List<Rectangle> fewRectangles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(rng.nextInt(300)+50, rng.nextInt(300)+50, rng.nextInt(100)+50, rng.nextInt(100)+50);
            r.setFill(randomColor());
            fewRectangles.add(r);
        }

        List<Ellipse> ovals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse(rng.nextInt(400)+50, rng.nextInt(400)+50, rng.nextInt(50)+50, rng.nextInt(50)+50);
            e.setFill(randomColor());
            ovals.add(e);
        }

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinSize(600, 600);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        Duration timepoint = Duration.ZERO ;
        Duration pause = Duration.seconds(1);

        KeyFrame initial = new KeyFrame(timepoint, e -> pane.getChildren().addAll(fewRectangles));
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(initial);

        for (Ellipse oval : ovals) {
            timepoint = timepoint.add(pause);
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(timepoint, e -> pane.getChildren().add(oval));
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        timeline.play();
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return new Color(rng.nextDouble(), rng.nextDouble(), rng.nextDouble(), 1.0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```